# How to set QT_ANGLE_PLATFORM programmatically from a QtQuick app?

Tags: qt, deployment, qml, qtquick2

On Windows, I've found that d3d9 works *way* smoother when resizing the window, compared with d3d12. However, I can't find a way to set QT_ANGLE_PLATFORM to "d3d9" from inside the program itself, not as environment variable.

There's `app.setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES);` to force the use of ANGLE, but I've found no way to configure ANGLE further.

Is there such a way? I don't want to set or change any environment variables on end-user machines. Or is this the wrong thing to do? 
Thanks!

Comment: Why not as environment variable?

Comment: I wonder if setting the environment variable at start of main (before initializing Qt application object etc) would work. Never tried, but it *should* work.

Comment: For the QtVirtualKeyboard I think I use [`qputenv()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qputenv) before creating the any QApplication and so on. Maybe this works for this problem, too. But the OP wants to do it without environment variables. There I don't have any idea.

Comment: Using qputenv() at the start of main() works perfectly! Thanks a lot!